# How to indicate an word exception for stemming in Hunspell

Tags: solr, hunspell

I am using Hunspell to stem words for a SOLR instance.  For the most part, it seems to be working well.

I'm using the OpenOffice dic/aff files.

However, there are some notable word exceptions, and I'd like to be able to remove these as candidates for stemming.

A great example is "skier", which stems to "sky" because of the following:

```
in the .dic file
sky/MDRSGZ

relevant rule in the .aff file
SFX R   y     ier        [^aeiou]y
```

Is there any way to indicate that `skier` and only `skier` should be left alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is a very common thing, just remove the "R"

```
sky/MDSGZ
```

But you may then want to add back in on another line "skier" and any other versions of it.

```
skier/MS
```

I have had to make numerous changes to this file, and now really wish there was a better option.
For example

- Butter -> Butt
- Corner -> Corn
- Easter -> East

And then another one that is really confusing,

- Wind == Wound

On my site before we fixed it if you searched for wind like in "wind power" you ended up with a bunch of bruises and bloody wounds. 
Because "wound" like in "I wound the clock" stemmed to wind.

We also decided to remove all RE prefixes. because things like

- remarkable -> mark
- remove -> move
- reset -> set
- restore -> store

So if you know of a better dictionary that is better for this please let me know. (I think the main problem is this dictionary is more intended for spell check then for stemming)

I would be willing to start and/or contribute to a git project for a real stemming dictionary to replace this spelling dictionary for everyone out there using this.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly as you suggest.  +1 for the idea of a stemming dictionary git project.  I think we could start with the standard dictionary and collaborate on these sorts of tweaks as you've described.

At least that way we're not all reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Exactly, well If I set one up I will let you know. You do the same, I need to look into the licensing quick, but pretty sure this would be allowed.

Comment: I've discussed this with my company, and we would certainly be interested in hosting this, or contributing to it.

I'll look into licensing too, and whoever gets there first, let's post a github link here once the repo is set up.

Comment: Sounds great, yeah I have still not gotten around too looking into the licensing, but I have looked around for a better dictionary and still have not found one better suited for stemming.

Comment: Yeah so I have the green light too. And now we want to remove basically every prefix, because approve <> disapprove, but I can't just drop the prefix, I will need to reapply the suffixes, because I want to stem (disapproving, disapproves) to "disapprove". So I am probably going to have to script something up to do that for me automatically.

Comment: I have created a repo for this https://github.com/publitek/stemming_dictionary but it is currently just the original from open office, I will apply my changes soon.

Comment: awesome -- I'm following the project and will contribute as we can.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried freeling? It is open sourced.

A demo page is here:
http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/demo/demo.php

When I pick english, pos tagging I get the following result:

```
you wound the clock?

you wind the clock? 
PRP VBD   DT  NN  ?
```

also skier, wind power all get the noun stems. It is a great stemmer and analyzer.

not sure about licensing. the download page: 
http://devel.cpl.upc.edu/freeling/downloads?order=time&desc=1